# Get the root folder path in php using include

Tags: php, include

I have php web application named **mywebsite** inside  c:\wamp\www\ .
 This folder consist of **featured/fashionWeek/database/Mysql.php** file. I use dirname(**FILE**) function to get path of folder from root so that I can place the folder to any place in public_html folder of live server.

It works fine in my localhost. I have following code inside wamp\www\mywebsite\featured\fashionWeek\database\Mysql.php The include(dirname(**FILE**); works fine that returns this path: C:/wamp/www/mywebsite/featured/fashionWeek/database

```
<?php  include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/Dbconfig.php') ;?>
```

But When I placed the mywebsite folder under public_html folder of the live server. It gives following errors:

```
Warning: include(/home/websitename/public_html/featured/fashionWeek/database/../config/Dbconfig.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/websitename/public_html/featured/fashionWeek/database/Mysql.php on line 3

Fatal error: include() [function.include]: Failed opening required '/home/websitename/public_html/featured/fashionWeek/database/../config/Dbconfig.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/websitename/public_html/featured/fashionWeek/database/Mysql.php on line 3
```

Comment: I think `include(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/Dbconfig.php')` works

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2152320/1528331

See if that helps. Also,

```
dirname(__FILE__) is the same as __DIR__
```

Answer (score 0):

To go backwards, i.e '..', you use the `dirname` function.

```
<?php
include(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)).'/config/Dbconfig.php');
```

Should work.

### More

It will be tiresome to manage these eventually, so I suggest in your original file, you define a ROOT constant. That will contain the absolute path to the root of your project. It's simple enough.

```
defined('ROOT') or define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
```

Answer (score 0):

a Little Bit Flabby , but it may help you

```
if(!function_exists('getRootdir'))
{
function getRootdir($NFILE)
{
$filefitter="";
while(!file_exists($filefitter.$NFILE))
$filefitter="../".$filefitter;
return $filefitter;
}
}
```

use

```
like  $rootpath=getRootdir("Root identifier folder / php file");
```

Comment: what is Root identifier folder? Would you please explain it

Comment: i said this is  Little Bit Flabby , if your Root Folder Contains any identifiable file or folder then the code will trace it , i used this 2yrs back to find root folder , my root folder  contains a folder "joystick" it was given so that fn returned the root folder relative to include a file
i used $root=getRootdir("joystick");
include ( $root ."rootinclude.php");